Let $G$ be a finite group, $\exists x,y \in G$ s.t. order of $x,y,xy$ are pairwise coprime. Prove $G$ is not solvable.
My attempt:
We know that $xy \neq yx$ for if so, then $\text{Ord}(x),\text{Ord}(y)|\text{Ord}(xy)$ which contradicts to the condition of coprime.
Thus, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in [G,G]$ is a nontrivial elements. And we also know that $G$ is not nilpotent.
My idea is to find some nontrivial elements fixed in the derived series, so that the derived series won't reaches $\{e\}$. But I don't know which one is. (May be $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$? but I don't know how to show.)

If $xy=yx$, then one could only say that the order of $xy$ divides the lcm of the orders of $x$ and $y$. It need not be divisible by the order of either $x$ or $y$.

@GeoffreyTrang Thank you. But I've already noticed this in my attempt. What about the next step?

If $x,y\in G$ then $xy\in G.$ Odd to include $xy$ in that conditional, so odd that I thought you might be trying to say something else at first.

Your comment about $Ord(x),Ord(y)\mid Ord(xy)$ would only be true if you assume $Ord(x)$ and $Ord(y)$ are relatively prime.

First, note that you must specify that $x$ and $y$ are not both the identity element of $G$. One approach to proving the given statement is using induction on $|G|$. The base case is trivial, so we may assume $|G| > 1$. Consider the quotient $\pi: G \to G/[G, G]$. We know that $|\pi(x)|, |\pi(y)|, |\pi(xy)|$ must also be pairwise relatively prime.

If all of $|\pi(x)|, |\pi(y)|, |\pi(xy)|$ are greater than $1$, we must have $[G, G] = 1$, for otherwise, the induction hypothesis would imply that $G/[G, G]$ is not solvable, which is absurd. Do you see how to proceed here?
If at least one of $|\pi(x)|, |\pi(y)|, |\pi(xy)|$ is equal to $1$, then the other two must be equal to each other. This forces all three to be equal to $1$ (since the numbers are pairwise relatively prime), so $x, y, xy \in [G, G]$. Do you see how to proceed here?


Thank you. I'm trying to catch up

+1. It might be slightly easier to understand to not use induction here. In the Abelian group $G/[G,G]$, it's not possible for the images to all have coprime order and these orders to all be larger than $1$.

@SteveD I am using the induction hypothesis in the second case.

Oh I see. The OP mentioned finding an element in every term of the derived series, which naturally fits here. But I guess that's a different type of induction.
